# sed treating arguments as literals

Tags: sed

I have a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1 > /proc/sys/kernel/hostname
sed -i "s/HOSTNAME=.*/HOSTNAME=$1/" /etc/sysconfig/network
```

When I run it, hostname file gets updated to whatever is passed in, but the network file gets a literal $1

I tried removing -i, changing it to single quotes and nothing works.

But googling tells me double quotes expands variables and this should work?

thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the value of `$1`?

Comment: OP wants to use the bash variable in `$1` as the new hostname in `/etc/sysconfig/network`

Comment: Your problem cannot be reproduced.  If `$1` contains a host name, it should indeed be interpolated by Bash into the `sed` script as long as it is between double quotes.  Perhaps you only tried single quotes after all?

Comment: no error message ? sample of set -vx of the runtime sed line ? (change server name if needed but with same structure)